# SQL: Alternative Option for Using "INTERVAL '1' YEAR" Function

Tags: sql

Hi anyone know an alternative way to pull last year's date? I used to utilize `INTERVAL '1' YEAR`, but it doesn't work anymore for some reason. For example,

```
SELECT id, data_load_dt
from school_inventory 
WHERE date_parse(data_load_dt, '%Y-%m-%d') IN (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1' YEAR)
```

Also, since data_load_dt is a string, I used date_parse to convert to time/date.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: "...it doesn't work anymore for some reason..." -- what's the error?

Comment: Why one (1) is between apostrophes? What DBRMS?

Comment: What is your actual database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle) ?

Comment: @TheImpaler - It doesn't populate. I get blank.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I use sql in jupyter notebook using pandas

Comment: `INTERVAL 1 YEAR` is not used by every kind of database. For example, if you're using SQL Server you probably want `DATEADD(year, -1, current_timestamp)`. Also, _PLEASE_ tell me the `data_load_dt` column isn't stored as a varchar. That would be **BAD**. Needing to parse the date in order to check it for a WHERE clause condition will absolutely destroy your performance. It means you'll have to parse every row, every time you run the query, and it will break the ability to use any indexes on the column.

Answer (score 2):

One problem (maybe not the only problem) is the result of the `INTERVAL` expression is **one value** for the `IN ()` expression. So this will only show records where `data_load_dt` is **exactly** from one year ago today.

You probably need this:

```
SELECT id, data_load_dt
FROM school_inventory 
WHERE date_parse(data_load_dt, '%Y-%m-%d') > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

But, not knowing your database, there might still be a **HUGE** improvement possible for this query. As written, the query will need to parse the `data_load_dt` value for **every row in the table** every time the query runs... even rows you don't need in the results. And thanks to cultural/internationalization issues, the parse operations tend to be *MUCH* slower and more error-prone than people expect. Even worse, this breaks any chance to use indexes that might be available for the column, since the parsed value no longer matches the index.

So the idea situation here is `data_load_dt` is **already** a DateTime value (again, not knowing the database type I can't be more specific on what this might look like). In that case, you can get equivalent code that will run **multiple orders of magnitude faster** like this:

```
SELECT id, data_load_dt
FROM school_inventory 
WHERE data_load_dt > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

We were able to remove ALL operations on the column, because logically if date/time value is in the prior year after truncating to a date-only, it will also be in the prior year before truncating to a date-only. This will allow us to use indexes again and remove the per-row conversions, so performance can improve drastically.

If `data_load_dt` is *NOT* already a DateTime value, you should **fix** this column, because the schema really is *BROKEN*.